# Mysql- How to sort the rows based on 2 columns in an irregular order?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I have a table with below structure

```
id| name | read | status   | is_assigned | created_at
1 | ABC  | 0    | ordered  | 0           | 2020-03-27 11:48:38
2 | XYZ  | 1    | accepted | 1           | 2020-03-27 11:48:38
3 | DEF  | 0    | ordered  | 0           | 2020-03-25 11:48:38
4 | JKL  | 1    | accepted | 0           | 2020-03-16 11:48:38
5 | GHI  | 1    | on-hold  | 1           | 2020-03-23 11:48:38
```

I want to priorities the sorting order as below :

1. Where read = 0
2. Where Status = ordered
3. Where status = accepted but is_assigned = 0
4. Sort By `created_at` `DESC`

The query I have is only valid for `created_at` and `read` columns i.e.

```
select * from orders order by read ASC, created_at DESC
```

How can I achieve the above sorting order for the described table and map this query in Laravel Query Builder

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate directly your logic in the `order by` clause, using MySQL's ability to evaluate conditions are `0/1` values:

```
order by
    (read = 0) desc,
    (status = 'ordered') desc,
    (status = 'accepted' and is_assigned = 0) desc,
    created_at
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. Just edited the question. How can I write this clause in `laravel Query Builder`?

Comment: @baig772: I don’t know about lavarel... From your question it seemed you wanted a pure SQL solution. You might want to ask a new question on how to translate the query to lavarel.